# Polymer 1: Reload importHref with modified content

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-1.0, web-component

In Polymer 1.x I am using importHref to dynamically load some HTML content. This works fine as expected. Is there a way to reload the same import dynamically with on-the-fly changed content. In other words,

- Import file using importHref.
- A section on the UI shows the imported HTML content that can be modified.
- After modification, clicking on a button destroys the previous import and reloads the new content.